# VSTS Build Failure MSB1009 Project File Does Not Exist

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines

I have a simple Solution tree:

Repository: DFW-SPF-Website
|-- Solution: DFWSPFWebsite
|-- |-- Project: DFWSPFWebsite

In my previous post I explained the contortions I had to go through to get VSTS to find my NuGet Packages. It took a while to lead its MSBuild process to even find the .sln file. Now MSBuild can't find the Project file.  Really?!

After countless incarnations, my current build settings are:

Solution:  $(build.sourcesDirectory)/DFWSPFWebsite/DFWSPFWebsite.sln

MSBuild Arguments:  /p:ProjectFile=$(build.sourcesDirectory)\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite.csproj

Platform: $(BuildPlatform)
Configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)
Clean: true
VS Version: 2015/2017/Latest (tried them all)
Control Options: Enabled

I can't get past the MSBuild error of:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite.sln" /nologo /nr:false /t:"Clean" /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a_tasks\VSBuild_abc-xyz\1.113.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=abc-xyz|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s\DFWSPFWebsite"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a_tasks\VSBuild_71abc-xyz\1.113.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:ProjectFile=D:\a\1\s\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite.csproj /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_abc-xyz_build_2_38"
>   MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
>   Switch: D:\a\1\s\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite.sln
>   Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a_tasks\VSBuild_71abc-xyz\1.113.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=abc-xyz|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s\DFWSPFWebsite"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a_tasks\VSBuild_71abc-xyz\1.113.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:ProjectFile=D:\a\1\s\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite.csproj /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_14abc-xyz_build_2_38"
>   MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
>   Switch: D:\a\1\s\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite.sln
>   Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

I never thought I'd miss my XAML deployment so much.

Comment: Please check in your project, if it’s exist project file in `DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite.csproj`. BTW, please also check **MSBuild Arguments**, it’s `/p:ProjectFile=$(build.sourcesDirectory)\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite.csproj` or `/p:ProjectFile=$(build.sourcesDirectory)\DFWSPFWebsite \DFWSPFWebsite.csproj`. Based on your log `/p:ProjectFile=D:\a\1\s\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite.csproj`, it seems the argument you set is `/p:ProjectFile=$(build.sourcesDirectory)\DFWSPFWebsite`.

Comment: If I look in the Code tab, the Project is there as are all required files.  In desperation, I've tried both versions of the Project path @Marina mentions as well as countless other variances.  I'm almost to the point of rebuilding the entire thing in VS 2015 under the suspicion that my base problem is that, even though I've migrated it through ever version of VS since then, I started the sln a long time ago in VS 2010.  The thing is, finding a .csproj file is such a simple thing - how can this not work?  And I still have more steps to deployment.  Troubling.

Comment: What if you leave the **MSBuild Arguments** empty? It defaultly find the project file in current working directly.

Comment: If I leave the MSBuild Arguments empty, I get the same error as above.  The Build finds the NuGet Packages folder and .sln file only because because I specify nearly absolute paths to them.  **\*.sln path variations haven't worked for any of my Build settings.  Now MSBuild finds them, but can't find the Project which is right under the Solution's nose - even if I lead MSBuild to the project by the hand (Arguments).  How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I GOT A CLEAN BUILD!!! Yes, ellipses are good – I was using the pre-release UI.  I also had to relocate a couple of external referenced dlls into a dll folder under the sln.  And, I had to remove the `<Target Name="EnsureBclBuildImported"…/>`, `<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build…/>` and `<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports"…/>` nodes from the csproj file. See [MSDN] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#migrating-to-automatic-restore) Because I’m not supposed to on SO, I will not send my incalculable appreciation to @Marina. :*

Answer (score -1):

First, please build your solution in VS 2015 to make sure it can build successfully. Then you can build in VSTS.

Since you only want to build one solution, so you can select `DFWSPFWebsite.sln` from `…` button both for nuget installer task and visual studio build task.

**Nugget installer:**

[image]

**Visual studio build:**

[image]

Comment: The sln has always built and run fine via  previous XAML deployments to Azure.

I updated to VS 2017 RC and now use the more flexible `**\*.sln`.  VSTS MSBuild now finds the .csproj file.  The error msg's url points to a 2013 page re NuGet 2.17 and NuGet package restoration which hasn’t been in VS since 2015.  I’m using NuGet 3.5.  >DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite\DFWSPFWebsite.csproj(739,5): Error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567.

Comment: I suspect that I need to follow the advice from @Marina re the NuGet Installer/Restore but I can’t find the pages she captured above.  VSTS itself doesn’t offer anything like that on its Code page.  What am I missing?

Comment: I listed the operation number, so you should click the `...` button firstly, then fing the `.sln`.

Comment: in my cases my branch's inheritance set to off, which lead to this issue, after set to on issue regarding the project file not found gone.